# Snowboard - overlap with Great Outdoors

Tags: discussion, scope

The Great Outdoors already covers some areas like [snowboarding](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/213/what-kind-of-snowboard-would-you-recommend-for-a-first-board), and [similar questions](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/213/what-kind-of-snowboard-would-you-recommend-for-a-first-board) are created here at Sports... Great Outdoors started sooner with these topics so maybe these topics should be continued to ask there.

Answer (score 4):

Oh Yeah, another site we overlap with!

This one is tricky because snowboarding is both a "sport" and a "recreational activity" if we follow our typical definition path competitive snowboarding is on topic here, recreational is not (this actually seems a bit silly to me though).

Basically, like sports participation with fitness and other cross site overlap, if they choose for it to be on topic for them that's great, its definitely on topic for us as well so lets not sweat it and move on.

Comment: But, if someone asked a question about snowboarding, and happened to not clarify whether it was for recreational or competitive, and knowledge of which it applied to wasn't necessary to answer the question, then we wouldn't make them tell us which it was for. For the record, I also find the distinction a bit silly.

Comment: I agree completely. It definitely is starting to break down. Sports that are definitely sports but primarily recreational (most people won't snowboard competitively, but its definitely still a sporting activity) are a rather difficult line...this goes for running as well...